# Is there a way to be notified when liquibase has released change log lock?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, liquibase

In Java/Spring boot application, I would like to know when liquibase has released   the change log lock during start up.    Are there any liquibase events that can be enabled or is there anyway to hook into the lifecycle to make this determination?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? It may be that there is a different way to get where you want.

Comment: I have alocking mechanism so that if two instances of my app are initializing,  only one will initialize while the 2nd waits til 1st complete.  A listener consumes events. When the  ApplicationReadyEvent is received, I can unlock and allow 2nd app can initialize.   I want to narrow the scope of the wait time for the second app as it may take a long time to completely initialize. I would prefer to allow my 2nd app to  initialize when liquibase is done initializing.  DataSourceInitializedEvent is published too early (when schema-platform.sql scripts run which is before liquibase execution.

Comment: If the answer I gave below is acceptable, can you please accept it as the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are willing to write a little bit of Java code, you could write your own implementation of the `LockService` interface that extends the `StandardLockService` and overrides just the `releaseLock()` method, using `super()` to call the original method, and then inserting whatever behavior you wanted to have afterwards.

You would also need to implement the `getPriority()` method and return a value higher than 1 (the standard priority).

All you have to do is have your jar on the classpath with the liquibase jar - liquibase will scan those jars, find that you have a class that implements LockService, and then when the `LockServiceFactory.getLockService()` method is called, your class will be returned.

Answer (score 0):

I had a quick look at [LockService](https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/blob/master/liquibase-core/src/main/java/liquibase/lockservice/StandardLockService.java) and [Spring bean](https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/blob/master/liquibase-core/src/main/java/liquibase/integration/spring/SpringLiquibase.java) don't see any functions to add listeners there. But you can add aspect using AOP libraries to be executed after releaseLock() is done.